# Oob Paring - how to?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, out-of-band

I am trying to build an app which interacts with a BLE device and uses OOB paring. There are no documentations regarding this anywhere and the bondOutOfband method in the Bluetooth library seems to be hidden. So, I am wondering, does the android system support OOB paring right now? or is there a different approach I can take for the paring.
Thanks

Comment: First thing i understand  nothing, the second thing it called OOP not obob

Comment: I dont know what you mean by obob or OOP, but I am talking about Out of Band paring (OOB) here.

Comment: Nordic semiconductor has some info and examples (for their chips) how to use it with Android https://infocenter.nordicsemi.com/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.nordic.infocenter.sdk5.v12.0.0%2Fnfc_ndef_ble_pair_message_module_dox.html